# Please explain how to create PHP's Phar stubs

Tags: php, stub, phar

I'm trying to create a very simple PHP CLI application that can be run as a [phar](http://php.net/manual/book.phar.php) file from the command line:

```
# php myProject.phar
```

This is what I've tried so far:

#### My Project

My project is in a directory called `MyProject` and it has these two files in it:

```
 |-- createPhar.php
 `-- bootstrap.php
```

#### bootstrap.php

The `bootstrap.php` file contains this:

```
<?php
print phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
print 'i am some script' . PHP_EOL;
```

When I run this script from my Ubuntu command line:

```
# cd MyProject 
# php bootstrap.php
```

I get the following output:

```
5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
i am some script
```

#### createPhar.php

The createPhar.php file is meant to turn the project into Phar archive. 
It looks like this:

```
<?php    
$phar = new Phar('MyProject.phar');
$phar->addFile('bootstrap.php');
$phar->setStub( $phar->createDefaultStub('bootstrap.php') );
```

When I run that script...

```
# php createPhar.php
```

... a new file called `MyProject.phar` is created in my project's directory.

```
|-- bootstrap.php
|-- createPhar.php
`-- MyProject.phar
```

#### Now here's the problem

When I run the phar file...

```
# php MyProject.phar
```

...I expect to see the same the same output that I got when when I ran the `bootstrap.php` script.

Instead I see nothing. No output at all. This implies that my `bootstrap.php` script is not being included by the default stub that was created by `$phar->createDefaultStub('bootstrap.php')`

I think I am misunderstanding how Phars and their stubs are being created. Could you, please, explain where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Your example does work for me. But try the `->setDefaultStub` shortcut (over ::createDefault and ::setStub) for testing.

Comment: Thanks mario. I tried using `->setDefaultStub` and it still did not work either. Its weird that you got it to work and I haven't. I suppose the problem is not to do with the code then.

Comment: My `PHP_VERSION` is `5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5`, but there was only one minor security bug fix related to the phar extension in between. It must be something else. Did you look at the resulting file with a hexeditor? Is the bootstrap content anywhere in it? (I got a plain php script with some admixed binary gibberish.)

Comment: Yep. Had a look at `MyProject.phar` and there is bootstrap code plus some gibberish in it. Thanks for your suggestions. I suspect I am doing something really stupid somewhere along the line - so gonna sleep on it and re-try tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question.

The method outlined in my question, above, is one correct way to create a phar / phar stub.

The reason why it did not work for me and *did* work for Mario (see his comment below the question), is because I had Suhosin installed and needed to tweak the settings.

Fixed using the [technique outlined here](http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/suhosinpharurlnotallowed):

> To fix, put:
>
> suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
>
> in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it like this:

**bootstrap.php;**

```
<?php
function go() {
    print phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
    print 'i am some script' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

then:

> php -r "require
>   'phar://Myproject.phar'; go();"

or don't have a function and it will execute whatever commands you have in there, but typically you would have some functions or class files in the phar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with a function and without. Ran ` php -r "require 'phar://Myproject.phar';"`. and got no output.

Comment: Whats really weird is that, if i delete the phar file alltogether, and then run ` php -r "ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); require 'phar://Myproject.phar';"` I still get no output.

Comment: Is this Linux and is SELinux enabled? Also any system errors?

Comment: Ahaaa! Yes. The system log shows up some stuff. I piped the output of the `syslog` file into `grep` to pick up on any mentions of php: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep php`. Looks like suhosin is meddling: `Jun 13 21:43:41 ubuntu suhosin[3264]: ALERT - Include filename ('phar:///MyProject/MyProject.phar/bootstrap.php') is an URL that is not allowed (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/MyProject/MyProject.phar', line 9)`

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Fixed using [the technique outlined here](http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/suhosinpharurlnotallowed).

Thanks for your help.