# distributing a php command line tool

Tags: php, shell

I have a php command line tool that I would like to share with the world. Well, actually I plan to write it, and it is a tool for loading design documents into couchdb, but that's not really the point.

Anyway, is there a best practice for packaging php scripts so that they can be distributed for easy installation? I'm thinking something along the lines of the good old "./configure & make & make install", but what to do for a php script? I have read about phar, but it seems that it is intended mainly for libraries. So any ideas? Or examples of how other projects have done this?

Comment: I think the main problem is that you're going to have to have everyone's computers running a web server, and / or installing PHP stand-a-lone.

Comment: @EM-Creations: You don't need a web-server to run a PHP script.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Did I say you need to run a web server and only a web server will do? No.

Comment: Here is the result: https://github.com/limikael/couchdesigntool Feedback much appreciated.. :)

Comment: @MikaelLindqvist Thanks for the link! I'm learning PHP and that Phar creation example on your source code was very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is a good example of how to package up the tool, both as a stand-alone set of source code, and code that can be run. I installed it as a phar and now can just run it anywhere as '`composer --options args`'

Comment: ah yep I just read up on composer a bit more, and it seems like a .phar script can actually be made to behave like an executable command. I read about it here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md where they suggest doing "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer". I think that's pretty much what I'm after. Will check the details...

Comment: PHAR is exactly what I was looking for, it just seems a bit non-straightforward and not particularly well documented how to actually create a PHAR archive. At least at the moment...

Comment: Take a look at the build process for Composer, and maybe also phpunit. There's also various blog posts, or the original info, at http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php

Comment: I finally managed to create it... This was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336144/please-explain-how-to-create-phps-phar-stubs

Answer (score 0):

There's [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) or the good old [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) that's still widely used, especially for CLI tools. To create your own PEAR channel, [Pirum](http://pirum.sensiolabs.org/) by SensioLabs (the Symfony guys) comes in handy.

For further reading, Stuart Herbert has a great [series on component based development](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/php-components/).

Comment: hm... I know about PEAR and composer, but still it seems like those tools are mainly used for installing _dependencies_ into a project. I would like to be able to create something that behaves more like a command, so that it will sit in the /bin directory and just be invokable from the command line by typing it's name.

Comment: if your component does not have dependencies, composer and PEAR are still useful. And especially PEAR is exactly what you are looking for. I.e. the installation of PHPUnit via PEAR goes like: `pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit`

Comment: hm.. but.. after installing PHPUnit, do I get a command line tool that I can run? which one?

Comment: well, you get PHPUnit. It's a ready to use command line tool.

Comment: Mikaels-iMac:~ mikael$ PHPunit
-bash: PHPunit: command not found

Comment: actually that doesn't work for me either... where is that file located on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CLIFramework](https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework) it handles subcommands, argument validation, option values (multiple, flag, optional, default) and a powerful zsh/bash completion generator.

A compile command is also out-of-box to help you compile your console application into a phar file for distributing.  (phpbrew uses this way to distribute the application to the world)

Here is a screencast of using zsh completion generator (it completes arguments and options):

[image: zsh completion generator]

There are also many popular applications using CLIFramework and GetOptionKit. e.g., [PHPBrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), [LazyRecord](https://github.com/c9s/LazyRecord)